# In an Azure event-hub created with 2 partition, the event-hub consumer tries to connect to 3rd and 4th partition

Tags: java, azure, azure-eventhub

I have set up an Azure event-hub with 2 partitions. I am using the Microsoft published code (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-java-get-started-send) to consume the messages from the event-hub. The consumer tries to connect to 3rd and 4th partitions even when they don't exist.

Error message:

> 2019-06-14 09:34:34,998 [ault|host]-1-13] - ERROR PartitionPump
>   - host host: 3: PartitionReceiver creation failed java.util.concurrent.CompletionException:
>   com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.EventHubException: The specified
>   partition is invalid for an EventHub partition sender or receiver. It
>   should be between 0 and 1. Parameter name: PartitionId
>   TrackingId:11c0c687fa3146ffaa97749d23abeae5_G27,
>   SystemTracker:gateway5, Timestamp:2019-06-14T04:04:34,
>   errorContext[NS: dev-sams-iot.servicebus.windows.net, PATH:
>   test/ConsumerGroups/$Default/Partitions/3, REFERENCE_ID:
>   6d2875_ae5_G27_1560485074529]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAccept(CompletableFuture.java:647)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniAccept.tryFire$$$capture(CompletableFuture.java:632)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniAccept.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.ExceptionUtil.completeExceptionally(ExceptionUtil.java:104)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.MessageReceiver.cancelOpen(MessageReceiver.java:361)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.MessageReceiver.onOpenComplete(MessageReceiver.java:351)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.MessageReceiver.onError(MessageReceiver.java:418)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.MessageReceiver.onClose(MessageReceiver.java:740)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.BaseLinkHandler.processOnClose(BaseLinkHandler.java:74)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.BaseLinkHandler.handleRemoteLinkClosed(BaseLinkHandler.java:113)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.BaseLinkHandler.onLinkRemoteClose(BaseLinkHandler.java:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.BaseHandler.handle(BaseHandler.java:176)
>     at
>   org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.EventImpl.dispatch(EventImpl.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.dispatch(ReactorImpl.java:324)
>     at
>   org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.process(ReactorImpl.java:291)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.impl.MessagingFactory$RunReactor.run(MessagingFactory.java:507)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 1):

While creating an event-hub, a storage account is also needed. Event-hub stores the details like partition count and messages of the partition in the storage account.

The above is because because initially I created an event-hub with four partitions and details of it were saved in the storage account. I deleted this event-hub and then created another event-hub with two partitions. Both the event-hubs used the same storage account.
Deleting the contents of the storage account solved the issue.